# "Cannot read property 'search' of undefined" - chrome.history.search

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I was trying to use chrome history APIs.

While using "chrome.history.search" getting error

> Cannot read property 'search' of undefined

```
chrome.history.search({
      'text': ''  
    },
    function(historyItems) {
// My TODO
});
```

Any solution, how to resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Not clear if previous answer was correct. If not, try adding `'history'` to your `permissions` array in `manifest.json`.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if you are running the code in a context where the API is not available.  The API only works in an extension's page (like a background view), not on a regular website.

Answer (score 0):

Adding 'history' to permissions works for me. And extensions page is not required. It works with regular .js